# Figuring out a specific string that can be used as a suggestion for a missing value

Tags: python, string, pandas

This is somewhat of a layered/loaded question and I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to best go about it.

The dataset has Brand (higher level) and Sub-Brand (lower level) that categorize various Product Descriptions. I've loaded it in a pandas dataframe to try to manipulate it.

Here's what a subset of the dataset looks like:

---

```
    Brand  Sub_Brand  Product_Description

    7-Up   NaN        7-Up Original Can 327ml

    7-Up   Diet       Diet 7-Up Bottle 327ml

    7-Up   Diet       Diet 7-Up Can 327ml

    7-Up   NaN        7-Up Lemon Lemon Peach 327ml

    7-Up   NaN        7-Up Lemon Lemon Grapefruit 327ml

    7-Up   NaN        7-Up Lemon Lemon Original 327ml
```

---

In this example, Diet is already populated in the Sub-Brand field because it represents the Sub-Brand associated with those products, but for other products such as the "Lemon Lemon" products, we're missing values. What I'm trying to accomplish is figure out a way to flush out "Lemon Lemon" as a good candidate to be placed within the Sub-Brand because it is a substring that keeps reappearing in multiple products.

It is easy to identify when you look at it yourself, I was hoping to figure out a code to flush it out.

```
values = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df['Product_Description'].iteritems():
    query = row.split()
    values = values.append(query)

flush = pd.DataFrame(values.groupby(0).size())
flush = flush.sort_values(by=[0],ascending=False)
flush['word'] = flush.index
flush = flush.reset_index(drop=True)
flush.columns = ['count', 'word']
flush = flush[~flush['word'].str.lower().isin(df['Brand'].str.lower())]
```

This helps me flush out "Lemon" as the most repetitive word and I can insert that in as a column as the suggestion for wherever that word appears as substring in the Product_Description column. However, it wouldn't be "Lemon Lemon" which is the desired outcome.

I also thought of using fuzzywuzzy and iterate the Production Description to do a token_sort_ratio match with all the other rows to see which Descriptions are consistently having high percentage match counts

For instance doing results in:

```
fuzz.token_set_ratio("7UP LEMON LEMON ORIGINAL", "7UP LEMON LEMON WHITE PEACH")
67
```

I was thinking of using anything that is > 60 storing them in a list and use the following function to grab the longest common substring

```
def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    answer = ""
    len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
    for i in range(len1):
        match = ""
        for j in range(len2):
            if (i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]):
                match += string2[j]
            else:
                if (len(match) > len(answer)): answer = match
                match = ""
    return answer
```

If I pass this through

```
test = longestSubstringFinder("7UP LEMON LEMON CUCUMBER MINT", "7UP LEMON LEMON WHITE PEACH").strip()
'7UP LEMON LEMON'
```

I can proceed to remove the Brand since it already exists within the dataframe for these two records and I eventually get a good Sub-Brand suggestion "Lemon Lemon"

I'm sure there is a better approach out there and I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction where I can put this all together and run through the entire dataset which is upwards of 340,000 rows

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some code, because I'm not sure I completely understand the question. Is this about db schemes? Do you want a better scheme or do you want to create a better query for a specific common string? I don't entirely understand what "subset of the dataset" is without some more context

Comment: what exactly did you try? and why did it not work? (ie you expected output X but you got output Y) ... this might help you http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/hws/hw7/index.html

Comment: Apologies for being so vague. The data set is a pipe delimitted .txt file which has Product Information and it is categorised by it's Brand and Sub-Brand, the subset that I posted is only focused on the data for 7-Up products that I used as a sample to get myself started out before I start looping the same code for the rest of the dataset.

Comment: I've updated the original question with a bit of code and my overall approach and some more clarification